# Where can I find a list of supported JS modules for VSCode?

Tags: javascript, module, visual-studio-code

It's evident that I can configure VSCode to recognize modules by creating a `jsconfig.json`, but I can't anywhere find a list of the supported module types.

*Can someone advise where I can find a list of supported VSCode JS modules?*

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES6",
        "module": "?"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm surprised that you aren't getting intellisense for `jsconfig.json`.

Try this.

Type the quote character `"`, then type `ctrl+space`. You should see something like this.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I didn't realize `ctrl+space` had that functionality. Any reason why I'm only getting a [few of the options](http://imgur.com/H39shwR)? I'm specifically looking to use es2015/es6 modules. I just checked to make sure that I was updated to the latest version.

Comment: I'm not sure. I am on the insiders channel so this may be something coming out in the most recent release. I believe the next generally available release is next week.

Comment: Hmm, weird. I am too.